# Raspberry PI / systemd: run script on shutdown/poweroff but not on restart

Tags: raspberry-pi, shutdown, systemd, raspbian

On Raspberry PI (running raspbian) I need to run script on **shutdown**/**poweroff**, but **not on reboot**.

My first attempt was to define a service as following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Power off service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/poweroff.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This worked, but the script was running also on reboot. So I tried to install it to different target:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target halt.target
```

But after this change, the script does not run at all.

What is the proper way of defining actions which should be executed on shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather around the net, the best option is to have `Conflicts=reboot.target` in the unit file (`[Unit]` section) and then executing the following in the script:

```
systemctl list-jobs | egrep -q 'reboot.target.*start'
```

If `reboot.target` is scheduled to be started, it's a reboot. Otherwise, it's not. If the command “succeeds”, the system is rebooting. Otherwise, it is shutting down. You could use it like this:

```
if ! systemctl list-jobs | egrep -q 'reboot.target.*start'; then
  echo Shutting down
fi
```

Comment: I've just tried `systemctl list-jobs` check you've suggested and it works indeed (thanks!), although I didn't add `Conflicts=reboot.target`. What is the purpose of conflicts declaration?

Comment: The `Conflicts=reboot.target` means your unit will have to be stopped before `reboot.target` can start. It may not be required because `reboot.target` appears to be the last thing on the list.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer solves the problem in the question. But it still was not exactly what I needed: the script was invoked too early, and I needed it to be executed as late as possible (the script actually turns the power off using the relay connected to RPi's `GPIO` pin)

After investing some more time, I found much simpler solution which did exactly what I was looking for:

1. Create directory `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-poweroff.service.d` if it does not exist yet
2. Create a new file `poweroff.conf` in `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-poweroff.service.d` directory:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/poweroff.sh
```

With this approach there is no need to add a new service